# org-link-open: Wrong number of arguments: (2 . 2), 1

Tags: org-link

lately I am often given this error, .e.g. when trying to open pdf files within Emacs. the stack trace reads

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (2 . 2) 1)
  org-docview-open("random.pdf")
  org-link-open((link (:type "docview" :path "random.pdf" :format bracket :raw-link "docview:random.pdf" :application nil :search-option nil :begin 437 :end 639 :contents-begin 555 :contents-end 637 :post-blank 0 :parent (paragraph (:begin 91 :end 4807 :contents-begin 91 :contents-end 4807 :post-blank 0 :post-affiliated 91 :parent nil)))) nil)
  org-open-at-point(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-open-at-point nil)
  #<subr call-interactively>(org-open-at-point nil nil)
  apply(#<subr call-interactively> org-open-at-point (nil nil))
  call-interactively@ido-cr+-record-current-command(#<subr call-interactively> org-open-at-point nil nil)
  apply(call-interactively@ido-cr+-record-current-command #<subr call-interactively> (org-open-at-point nil nil))
  call-interactively(org-open-at-point nil nil)
  command-execute(org-open-at-point)
```

can someone tell me what the problem is and how to fix it? Im not org 9.3.6 with Emacs 26

Comment: Is the effect reproducible with `emacs -Q` and `M-x package-initialize RET`?